# Undefined is not a function, React Native and Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to make an authentification flow and this error keeps coming up after I wrote the sign in function.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This is my code in LoginScreen.js where I have a form and two buttons, one for login and one for signup, I think the error comes from the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
} from 'react-native';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';
import {
  getAuth,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import app from './firebase';
const auth = getAuth(app);
const LoginScreen = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        navigation.navigate('Home');
        const uid = user.uid;
        // ...
      } else {
        // User is signed out
        // ...
      }
    });
  }, []);

  const handleSignUp = () => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log(user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
      });
  };

  const handleLogin = () => {
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        // ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
      });
  };

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding">
      <MaterialCommunityIcons name="recycle" size={80} color="#3CB371" />
      <Text style={styles.title}>Recyclify</Text>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Email"
          value={email}
          onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Password"
          value={password}
          onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
          style={styles.input}
          secureTextEntry
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleLogin} style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={handleSignUp}
          style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOutline]}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonOutlineText}>Register</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};


export default LoginScreen;
```

Comment: Which button are you pressing?